# How to convert different string value to respective 'YYYY' int format?

Tags: sql-server-2005, xml

I'm inserting values into `table` from `xml` as:

```
DECLARE @XMLRESULT XML

DECLARE @tbl_XMLResult TABLE
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Status VARCHAR(50),
    Address VARCHAR(250),
    ListPrice INT,
    SoldPrice INT,
    YearBuilt INT   
)

EXEC usp_GetReportResult @query = @query, @ReportName = @ReportName, @XMLResult = @XMLRESULT OUTPUT

INSERT INTO @tbl_XMLResult
(
    Status,
    Address,
    ListPrice,
    SoldPrice,
    YearBuilt
)
SELECT
    L.value('(ListingStatus/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Status,
    L.value('(PMCReportData/Listing_StreetAddress/text())[1]','VARCHAR(250)') AS Address,
    L.value('(ListPrice/text())[1]','INT') AS ListPrice,
    L.value('(ClosePrice/text())[1]','INT')AS SoldPrice,
    L.value('(YearBuilt/text())[1]','INT')AS YearBuilt
FROM @XMLRESULT.nodes('/Results/Report/Listings/Listing')AS Result(L)
```

But as shown above for `YearBuilt` column the datatype is `int` in which we are storing just `year` on which property is built. And accordingly subsequent `calculations` are done. But some of the time the values for `YearBuilt` comes from `xml` as in `format`

- "New"
- "0-5 Yrs"
- "70+"

But when above type of result for `YearBuilt` comes in `xml` we are getting `conversion error`.
Need to get values from above result as if YearBuilt as:

- "New"     - Here we want consider current year and store result as 2016 current year.
- "0-5 Yrs" - 0-5Yrs. Here consider upper limit, i.e. 5. So store result as 2011 as(2016 - 5 = 2011)
- "70+"     - consider 70 as => 2016 - 70 Year = 1946

How we can do this to store appropriate result into `@tbl_xmlResult`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value from the XML as a string and do some string manipulation in a case statement.

Example with simplified XML:

```
declare @X xml = '
<YearBuilt>2017</YearBuilt>
<YearBuilt>New</YearBuilt>
<YearBuilt>0-5 Yrs</YearBuilt>
<YearBuilt>70+</YearBuilt>
';

select case
         when T.Value = 'New' then year(getdate())
         when T.Value like '%Yrs' then year(getdate()) - cast(replace(stuff(T.Value, 1, charindex('-', T.Value), ''), 'Yrs', '') as int)
         when T.Value like '%+' then cast(left(T.Value, charindex('+', T.Value) - 1) as int)
         else cast(T.Value as int)
       end
from @X.nodes('/YearBuilt') as Y(X)
  cross apply (
              select Y.X.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(10)')
              ) as T(Value);
```